# How to write GMM (Gaussian Mixture Model) in C?

Tags: c, mixture-model

How can I write GMM (Gaussian Mixture Model) in C. There are some implementations in Matlab but I am looking for some documentation about it and example code in C not in  C++.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV has an implementation of a GMM that is used for their GrabCut implementation.
You can find it for example [here](http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/grabcut.cpp).

edit: I just noticed you were looking for an implementation in C. The OpenCV implementation is using C++. But maybe you can use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find an implementation in C:

https://engineering.purdue.edu/~bouman/software/cluster/

Answer (score 1):

How about the [mixture model in Apophenia](http://apophenia.info/group__models.html#gaf085564a8adc67ba156c4cd1db8145e3)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a GMM implementation available in vlfeat, a C library for computer vision. https://www.vlfeat.org/api/gmm.html