# Mixture of Gaussians - C

Tags: c, opencv, gaussian, mog

Does anybody know of a good implementation of the Mixture of Gaussians (must be for C), which is able to work with OpenCV?

I know there's an undocumented implementation already included in OpenCV for C++, however this must be in C. I don't fancy reinventing the wheel if there's already one out there which will do what I want.

Comment: There are some answers in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571802/how-to-write-gmm-gaussian-mixture-model-in-c

Answer (score 0):

I found this obsolete C interface of [Expectation Maximization](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/legacy/doc/expectation_maximization.html) in OpenCV, hope it helps.